# Assign buffer an attribute based on the largest polygon inside

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder

I would like to assign a buffer polygon a value from another layer. I have cliped the two layers together. I then tried to dissolve the new layer by buffer ID, but I could not manage to get the largest area inside to be the value for the whole buffer.

I tried to do it by using calculate field, but im not very good at python.

[image: There are two polygons inside the buffer after the clip, but I only want the largest one of them to represent the polygon.]

Comment: I Think what you want is Spatial Join or Intersect. Add a screenshot

Comment: @BERA I added a picture now. I tried the spatial join, but I cant use the largest area to classify the attribute of the buffer polygon.

Comment: Look at https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/154749/get-max-value-from-multiple-points-surrounding-buildings

Comment: @jbosq I get the method for points, but im going to use it on polygons and based on the area the polygons. I dont think your method is applicable here.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using [Spatial Join](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/analysis/spatial-join.htm). You can set your parameters to those shown in the image.

[image]

Field mapping is the trick, when you choose a one_to_one join only one value can be joined for each feature in your buffer, the merge rule is used to decide which value (in your case maximum). 
If "another layer" doesn't already have an area field simply create one and Calculate Geometry. If the area field name is not unique (as in the example picture) set the merge rule on the renamed field in the Join Feature (e.g. "Shape_Area" was automatically renamed to "Shape_Area_1" in this case)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I tried this one, but that would not work for me. I would stil not get the featyre connected to the largest shape, only the first one. It worked using the method used in the similar question.